# Given a list of digits, construct the largest number divisible by 3

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

**What is the performance of this program? What should I do differently to optimize performance (O(n))? How would you grade it relative to what defines an optimal, elegantly-written program?**

Input: A list l that has a length between 1 and 9 elements, consisting
of the numbers from 0-9. The length of l and the values of the
elements are both random.
Output: The largest number that can be constructed from the list that
is divisible by 3. If not possible, return(0).

Test Case:
input: l = [3,1,4,1,5,9]
output: 94311

```
def solution(l):
    sum = 0
    
    # Sum the elements of l
    for elem in l:
        sum += elem
        
    # Determine whether l contains a number divisible 
    # by 3, using the modulo operator. If sum modulo
    # 3 is equivalent to 1 or 2, we split the elements
    # into two separate lists, q1 and q2.
    if (sum < 3):
        return(0)
    elif (sum % 3 == 0):
        l.sort(reverse=True)
        x = ''
        for i in l:
            x = x + str(i)
        return(int(x))
    else:
        q1 = [x for x in l if x % 3 == 1]
        q1.sort(reverse=False)
        q2 = [x for x in l if x % 3 == 2]
        q2.sort(reverse=False)
        l = [x for x in l if x % 3 == 0]
    
    # Remove proper elements such that the
    # sum of l is divisible by 3.
    if (sum % 3 == 1):
        if (len(q1) != 0):
            q1.pop(0)
        elif (len(q2) >= 2):
            q2.pop(0)
            q2.pop(0)
    elif (sum % 3 == 2):
        if (len(q2) != 0):
            q2.pop(0)
        elif (len(q1) >= 2):
            q1.pop(0)
            q1.pop(0)
    
    # Assemble largest number in l divisible
    # by 3 by extending l to q1 and q2.
    l.extend(q1)
    l.extend(q2)
    l.sort(reverse=True)
    
    # Recheck sum of l and test for
    # divisbility. If divisible by 3
    # concatenate the elements of l into x.
    sum2 = 0
    if (len(l) > 0):
        for elem in l:
            sum2 += elem
        if (sum2 % 3 == 0):
            x = ''
            for i in l:
                x = x + str(i)
            return(int(x))
        else:
            return(0)
    else:
        return(0)
```

Comment: I have changed the keyword variable sum to sum1.

Comment: > What is the performance of this program? If you mean about the runtime, do you try to run the code on your machine? How long it takes?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. "The largest number divisible by 3" out of what? Why you sum the numbers in the list? Please clarify the description of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Marc. I made changes to the descriptions of the input and the output. I sum the numbers to determine visibility by 3.

Comment: Just on the algorithm. If you start with a descendingly sorted array of digits and start discarding digits at the end.you might stop at the first found triple as being the largest triple. Removing one digit > removing 2 digits, The remainder of the triple being the remainder of the digit resp. two digits.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, (design,) program and code the way *you* think about the problem.
(This may change, as may requirements: Make oncoming change easy, if not safe.
This includes avoiding duplicate code - handling non-zero remainders, computing the result from the digits.)
(And leave worrying about *performance* to when there *is* an indication this is (promising to be) a problem. *1 to 9 elements*? No problem if what's waiting is human.)

Don't write, never publish uncommented/undocumented code.
Python got it right specifying [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) such that it is easy to copy them with the code, and tedious to copy the code without them.

The are many angles to view the problem at hand - leveraging [collection.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):
(one rubber point for spotting deviations from the Style Guide)

```
from collections import Counter

def biggest_multiple_of_3(digits, base=10):
    """ Return the biggest multiple of 3 possible by 
        rearranging some of the digits (0 if impossible). 
        (works for base 3b+1 for any non-negative b.)
    """
    if not digits:
        return 0
    # approach: leave unused 1. fewest 2. smallest digits as needed
    ascending = sorted(int(d) for d in digits)  # int(d, base) mandates d string
    counts = Counter(d % 3 for d in ascending)
    remainder = (counts[1] + 2*counts[2]) % 3
    if 0 == remainder:
        rid, count = 3, 0
    elif 0 < counts[remainder]:
        rid, count = remainder, 1
    elif 1 < counts[3 - remainder]:
        rid, count = 3 - remainder, 2
    else:
        return 0
    if len(digits) <= count:  # entirely redundant
        return 0
    power = 1
    multiple = 0
    for d in ascending:
        # print(power, d, rid, count)
        if 0 < count and d%3 == rid:
            count -= 1
        else:
            multiple += d*power
            power *= base
    return multiple

def solution(l):              # don't let interface requirements ruin your code
    biggest_multiple_of_3(l)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    biggest_multiple_of_3('314159')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made the following changes to my code. This version seems to be less chaotic, has better structure, more pythonic code, and more efficient use of each word of code.

```html
def solution(l):
    # Declare variables
    sum1 = sum(l)
    rem = sum1 % 3
    
    # Check value of remainder using modulo
    if rem > 0:
        q1 = sorted([x for x in l if x % 3 == 1])
        q2 = sorted([x for x in l if x % 3 == 2])

        # Depending on the remainder, remove the elements that
        # will produce the largest number divisible by 3.
        if rem == 1 and len(q1) != 0:
            l.remove(q1[0])
        elif len(q2) >= 2:
            l.remove(q2[0])
            l.remove(q2[1])
        elif rem == 2 and len(q2) != 0:
            l.remove(q2[0])
        elif len(q1) >= 2:
            l.remove(q1[0])
            l.remove(q1[1])
            
        # If l is empty, sort l into descending order.
        # If l is not empty, convert l to string.
        if len(l) != 0:
            l.sort(reverse=True)
            x = ''
            for i in l: 
                x = x + str(i)  
        else:
            return(0)
    # If rem == 0, sort l into descending
    # order, and convert l to a string.
    elif rem == 0:
        l.sort(reverse=True)
        x = ''
        for i in l: 
            x = x + str(i)
    # Convert x and return an integer.  
    return(int(x))
```

Comment: How I'd grade the code? There are still way too many single-letter variable names used and the comments describe what the code does literally instead of why that code is doing something. That's a good indication you're a beginner, it's not acceptable in production code.

Answer (score 1):

The original solution and the proposed solutions include a step of sorting the list of digits. So technically, they are O(n log n), but the list is at most 9 digits long, so the difference may not be noticeable unless the code is being run many (millions?) of times.

Nevertheless, here is an O(n) version:

```
from collections import Counter

def make_number(digits: [int]) -> int:
    result = 0
    
    for digit in digits:
        result = 10*result + digit
    
    return result


def solution(digits: [int]) -> int:
    """Returns the largest number that that is divisible by 3 that can be made
       from the digits. Returns 0 if it is not possible to make a number 
       divisible by 3. (That is somewhat ambiguous, because 0 is divisible
       by 3, you can't determine whether 0 means failure,
       or there was a 0 in digits).
    """

    if not digits:
        return 0
    
    # Prepopulate keys in the counter in descending order.
    count = Counter(dict.fromkeys(range(9,-1,-1), 0))
    count.update(digits)
    
    remainder = sum(digits) % 3
        
    if remainder == 0:
        return make_number(count.elements())
    
    # One group is [1, 4, 7] and the other is [2, 5, 8].
    # Which is which depends on remainder.
    remainder_group = range(remainder, 10, 3)
    other_group = range(3 - remainder, 10, 3)

    # If possible, remove a single digit, where digit % 3 == remainder.
    # The `groups` are in ascending order so small digits are removed before 
    # large ones.
    # If 'any()' is True, 'index' will be the digit that cause it to succeed.
    if any(count[(index:=digit)] for digit in remainder_group):
        count[index] -= 1
        return make_number(count.elements())

    # Otherwise, remove 2 digits from the other group
    if any(count[(index:=digit)] for digit in other_group):
        count[index] -= 1

        if any(count[(index:=digit)] for digit in other_group):
            count[index] -= 1
            return make_number(count.elements())

    return 0
```

Each of `count.update()`, `sum()` and `make_number()` are O(n). Everything else is O(1) (i.e., constant time).